# How to move an drag and drop item to a certain position, when located over canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am working on a Tablet-environment with draggable objects.
The drag & drop works, it is even possible to drag several objects at once, when implemented.

References are :

[Reference 1](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/Tutorials/Drag_and_Drop) & [Reference 2](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/touch-friendly-drag-and-drop)

This is how the current version of my code looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta 
     name='viewport' 
      content='width=50px, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0,' 
     /> 
<!-- 

Refernces:
* https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/Tutorials/Drag_and_Drop
* https://mobiforge.com/design-development/touch-friendly-drag-and-drop
-->
     
<style> 

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  top: 100px
}
  
main1 {
  position: relative;
  }

div1 {

  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  background: red;
  border: 0px solid #666;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} 

</style>  
  <title>Clean up</title>
</head>

<body>



<div id ="container">
</div> 
 
<main1 id="main1">
    <div1 class="draggable" id="d1-0""></div1>
</main1>

  
<script>

var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('draggable');
 
  for(var i=0;i<nodeList.length;i++) {
    var obj = nodeList[i];
    obj.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
      var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
      
      // Place element where the finger is
      event.target.style.left = touch.pageX + 'px';
      event.target.style.top = touch.pageY + 'px';
      event.preventDefault();
    }, false);
  } 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The idea is, that the red box (div1) can be moved, dragged and dropped everywhere on the screen. But it needs to be moved to its very initial starting position, when it enters the yellow canvas. (The idea is to "clean up" and "move objects back to where they came from".)

Comment: You want the `red div` to snap into a specific location as soon as it enters the `yellow div` or when you release the mouse?

Comment: Thank you, Alex, for your quick response! When the red div enters the yellow div and the mouse is released.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery UI's draggable and touch punch for mobile friendliness

Let me know if this is close to what you're looking for and we can adjust as needed

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div1').draggable();
  $('#container').droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
       alert("You dropped the red on the yellow");
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#animateBtn", function() {
    //Simple animate w/ just specifying the offsets
    //$('#div1').animate({top:"250px", left:"250px"});
    
    //Other animate options
    $('#div1').animate({
        top:"15px",
        left:"15px"
      }, {
        duration:555, //Animation time in pixels
        easing:"easeOutQuart"  //See https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/
      }); 
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  top: 100px
}
  
body {
  position: relative;
}

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  background: red;
  border: 0px solid #666;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#animateBtn {
  position:fixed;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:3px 5px;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  border-radius:6px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta 
     name='viewport' 
      content='width=50px, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0,' 
     /> 
  <title>Drag and Drop</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div> 
  <div class="draggable" id="div1"></div>
  <div id="animateBtn">Animate</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Tom Gerken! Yes, that is really good, thank you! The next issue would then be to add a function to move the red div to certain coordinates on the screen - does it make sense to do this with animate?

Comment: I assume a  function to move the red div to certain coordinates on the screen has to be added - Which means, that the initial coordinates of the red div are required (could they be extracted from the #div1 in css?) and that there needs to be a function to move the red div to the respective coordinates. I found several tutorials on how to move an object relatively to the current position (e.g [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_animate.asp]), which is not really, what I was searching for.

Comment: No prob Melanie, yeah use jQuery's animate function, specifying the top and left offsets (often you'll need to add half the width/ height of the object if you are trying to center it somewhere)  I added an example to my answer

Comment: I tried to include something like this into the code of the function, but I seem to have made a mistake, as the div is not draggable anymore: <code> $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div1').draggable();
  $('#container').droppable({
    drop: function( 100, 0 ) {
       var d = document.getElementById('div1');
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = 100 +'px';
  d.style.top = 0 +'px';
    }
  });
}); </code>

Comment: Wow, that is really great! Thank you very much @Tom Gerken! I will try to merge the animation with the drop function (to replace the alert with the animation)!

Comment: Ok, I tried to do this, but I did not manage to make it work. I tried this:     $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#div1').draggable();
      $('#container').droppable({
        drop: function() {
        $('#div1').animate({
            top:"15px",
            left:"15px"
          }, {
            duration:555,
            easing:"easeOutQuart"
          }
        }
      });

Comment: Found a bracket-mistake, now it works! Will post the code below! :) Thank you so much!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta 
     name='viewport' 
      content='width=50px, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0,' 
     /> 
  <title>Drag and Drop</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>


<style> 

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  top: 100px
}
  
body {
  position: relative;
}

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  background: red;
  border: 0px solid #666;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


</style>  
  <title>Clean up</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container"></div> 
  <div class="draggable" id="div1"></div>
  <!--<div id="animateBtn">Animate</div>-->

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div1').draggable();
  $('#container').droppable({
    drop: function() {
    $('#div1').animate({top:"100px", left:"100px"});
    }
  });
 });
 


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a mention of jQuery but [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp) has a working example that goes without. Could you some touchup though:

```
/**
 * Make object draggable
 * @param {Element} element 
 */
const addDraggable = (element)=> {
    let pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;

  const dragMouseDown = e => {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    [pos3, pos4] = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  };

  const elementDrag = e => {
        console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    [pos1, pos2] = [pos3 - e.clientX, pos4 - e.clientY];
    [pos3, pos4] = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
    // set the element's new position:
    [element.style.top, element.style.left] = 
            [(element.offsetTop - pos2) + "px", (element.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px"];
  };

  const closeDragElement = _ => {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  };

  element.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event=> {
  _('#logo-top').addEventListener('click', event=> {
    event.stopPropagation();
    _('#logo-top').classList.toggle('active');
    _('nav').forEach( n=> n.classList.toggle('collapsed') );
    _('main').classList.toggle('extended');
  });

    addDraggable( _('#help-text') );
    _( '#help' ).addEventListener( 'click', ()=>{ _('#help-text').classList.toggle('active')} );
    _( '#help-text-close' ).addEventListener( 'click', ()=>{_('#help-text').classList.toggle('active')}  );

});
```

Another way would be to use the [Drag Operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations)