# How to move an drag and drop several items to a certain position independently, when located over area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

Following up to the question 
[How to move an drag and drop item to a certain position, when located over canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801496/how-to-move-an-drag-and-drop-item-to-a-certain-position-when-located-over-canva)
another question occurred:
When implementing several animated divs they all react, if the animation is triggered, i.e. if one div is over the yellow container. But only the one should react, which is over the yellow container.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta 
     name='viewport' 
      content='width=50px, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0,' 
     /> 
  <title>Drag and Drop</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>


<style> 

#container1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  top: 100px
}

#container2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  top: 100px
}
  
body {
  position: relative;
}

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  background: red;
  border: 0px solid #666;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  background: blue;
  border: 0px solid #666;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


</style>  
  <title>Clean up</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container1"></div> 
   <div id="container2"></div> 
  <div class="draggable" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="draggable" id="div2"></div>
  <!--<div id="animateBtn">Animate</div>-->
    <div type="image" align="bottom" width="45px" src="refresh.png" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">
<script>

$(document).ready(function( event, ui ) {
  $('#div1').draggable();
  $('#container1').droppable({
    drop: function() {
    $('#div1').animate({top:"100px", left:"100px"});
    }
  });
 });
 
$(document).ready(function(event, ui) {
  $('#div2').draggable();
  $('#container2').droppable({
    drop: function() {
    $('#div2').animate({top:"100px", left:"100px"});
    }
  });
 });
 
var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('draggable');
 
  for(var i=0;i<nodeList.length;i++) {
    var obj = nodeList[i];
    obj.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
      var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
      
      // Place element where the finger is
      event.target.style.left = touch.pageX + 'px';
      event.target.style.top = touch.pageY + 'px';
      event.preventDefault();
    }, false);
  } 
  


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any solution on how to only animate the one div, that is located over the yellow div? Tried to use accept: '#div1', which I could not get to work, yet...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (and an error I did ;)) it works with accept, see code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta 
     name='viewport' 
      content='width=50px, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0,' 
     /> 
  <title>Drag and Drop</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>


<style> 

#container1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  top: 100px
}

#container2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  top: 100px
}
  
body {
  position: relative;
}

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  background: red;
  border: 0px solid #666;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  background: blue;
  border: 0px solid #666;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


</style>  
  <title>Clean up</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container1"></div> 
   <div id="container2"></div>
  <div class="draggable" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="draggable" id="div2"></div>
  <!--<div id="animateBtn">Animate</div>-->
    <div type="image" align="bottom" width="45px" src="refresh.png" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">
<script>

$(document).ready(function( event, ui ) {
  $('#div1').draggable();
  $('#container1').droppable({
  accept: '#div1',
    drop: function() {
    $('#div1').animate({top:"100px", left:"100px"});
    }
  });
 });
 
$(document).ready(function(event, ui) {
  $('#div2').draggable();
  $('#container2').droppable({
  accept: '#div2',
    drop: function() {
    $('#div2').animate({top:"100px", left:"100px"});
    }
  });
 });
 
var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('draggable');
 
  for(var i=0;i<nodeList.length;i++) {
    var obj = nodeList[i];
    obj.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
      var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
      
      // Place element where the finger is
      event.target.style.left = touch.pageX + 'px';
      event.target.style.top = touch.pageY + 'px';
      event.preventDefault();
    }, false);
  } 
  


</script>

</body>
</html>
```